# $\sigma (A)$ is countable and $\sigma(A) = \partial \sigma(A) = \sigma(A)\hat{}$ (Spectral Theory of a compact operator)

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

I'm studying Conway's Functional Analysis.

In Chaper VII.7 (The Spectral Theory of a Compact Operator) first paragraph,

> $\mathcal{B}_0(\mathcal{X})$ is the algebra of all compact operators. If $A \in \mathcal{B}_0(\mathcal{X})$ , then $\sigma(A)$ refers to the spectrum of $A$ as an element of $ \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{X})$. If $\mathcal{A} =\mathcal{B}_0(\mathcal{X}) + \mathbb{C} $, then $\mathcal{A}$ is Banach algebra with identity, and we consider $\sigma_{\mathcal{A}}(A)$. Since $\sigma(A) \subset \sigma_{\mathcal{A}}(A)$ and $\partial \sigma_{\mathcal{A}}(A) \subset \partial\sigma(A)$.
> Using fact that $\sigma(A)$ is countable, $\sigma(A) = \partial \sigma(A) = \sigma(A)\hat{}$. Thus $\sigma(A) = \sigma_{\mathcal{A}}(A)$

I have question about, why $\sigma(A) = \partial \sigma(A) = \sigma(A)\hat{}$ holds indicate $\sigma(A) = \sigma_{\mathcal{A}}(A)$. Thanks. I think this logic would be easy and intuitively right, but how to prove it..?

Comment: What does $\sigma(A)\hat$ mean?

Comment: @Ruy It is polynomially convex set. Sorry for not sufficient explanation.

Comment: For any countable subset $F\subset\mathbb{C}$, $\partial F=F$. So $\sigma(A)=\partial\sigma(A)\supseteq\partial\sigma_{\mathcal{A}}(A)$.

Comment: @chrystomath then..? $\sigma_{\mathcal{A}}(A) 
 \supseteq \sigma(A)=\partial\sigma(A)\supseteq\partial\sigma_{\mathcal{A}}(A)$ makes $\sigma(A) = \sigma_{\mathcal{A}}(A)$?